# Connecting to cassandra using java without passing credentials

Tags: java, security, ssl, cassandra, datastax

I am using datastax cassandra I have some queries related to cassandra connectivity using JAVA, Below is the code which i am currently using to connect to cassandra.

```
cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint("127.0.0.1").withCredentials("cassandra", "cassandra").withPort(9042).build();
```

But as this has some security concerns like username and password is visible i can't go for this approach.
Is there any way of connecting securely without passing username and password

I have gone some articles and found that we can go by **[Using SSL connections](https://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-devcenter/devcenter/connecingClusterSsl.html)** but couldn't get exactly how to do, it would be great if anyone can elaborate SSL approach

And also I want to know is there any other approach in doing this

Comment: you can move the username and password to a configuration file..

Comment: Check if this(withSsl()) works for you, and yeah, of course, you should store your credentials separately.


Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoints("127.0.0.1").withCredentials("username", "password").withSSL().build();

Comment: @redflar3 I agree with you, but I am looking some more secure way if any

Comment: @PratikAmbani do I need to create ssl certificates in my cluster nodes inorder to use this?

Comment: @ShabarinathVolam Obviously! You'll require SSL Certificate in cluster nodes. Let me know if you face any connectivity issue from code.

Comment: @PratikAmbani I don't have any SSL certificates created in my cluster nodes my program is not working, Can u brief how we can do that

Comment: @ShabarinathVolam You know how to generate keystore and stuff right?

Comment: @PratikAmbani I am aware of that, but even in ur example I see we are using username and password my intention is not to provide them in code

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of online resources to help you (not sure are you using dse or community):

http://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-dse/datastax_enterprise/sec/secTOC.html

http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/4-simple-rules-when-using-the-datastax-drivers-for-cassandra

https://www.pythian.com/blog/cassandra-3-9-security-feature-walk/

https://www.slideshare.net/DataStax/securing-cassandra-for-compliance